# Conditionals worked aberrantly in python:

Tags: python, numpy

Trying to go through some basic algorithms:

Racking my head around this block of code I wrote that doesn't always work:

```
for j in range(1,n): #over range of array 
       array = np.random.randint(1,1000,n);    
       test = 0;
       if (array[j] > array[1] and array[j] == array.max()):
           plot=plot+1
           test = 1;
           break
       elif (array[j] > array[1]):
           test = 2;
           break
print(array)
print("j = ",j)
print(test)
```

Problem is I get outputs like this:

```
[841 744 623 804 957]
j =  4
1
```

The code is supposed to start at position `1` and count forward. If it meets an array value greater than the position at 1, should add one to plot and exit the for loop (if that array value is the maximum). If it is just greater than `array[1]`, then exit the `for` loop without incrementing plot by `1`.

Cannot figure out why `J` has to iterate all the way to `4` in that particular array above, it should have stopped at `3`, incremented plot by `1` and exited the loop.

Comment: You're creating a new random array each loop, is that intended? It's a different array each time, you're not simply iterating through the printed array.

Comment: Use `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` to debug line by line. Type `step` or `n` to move from line to line

Comment: I think Weaving was right - moved the np.array.randint out and it works better.